# Reading a big JSON file with multiple objects in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, performance, pandas-datareader

I have a big GZ compressed JSON file where each line is a JSON object (i.e. a python dictionary).

Here is an example of the first two lines:

```
  {"ID_CLIENTE":"o+AKj6GUgHxcFuaRk6/GSvzEWRYPXDLjtJDI79c7ccE=","ORIGEN":"oaDdZDrQCwqvi1YhNkjIJulA8C0a4mMZ7ESVlEWGwAs=","DESTINO":"OOcb8QTlctDfYOwjBI02hUJ1o3Bro/ir6IsmZRigja0=","PRECIO":0.0023907284768211919,"RESERVA":"2015-05-20","SALIDA":"2015-07-26","LLEGADA":"2015-07-27","DISTANCIA":0.48962542317352847,"EDAD":"19","sexo":"F"}{"ID_CLIENTE":"WHDhaR12zCTCVnNC/sLYmN3PPR3+f3ViaqkCt6NC3mI=","ORIGEN":"gwhY9rjoMzkD3wObU5Ito98WDN/9AN5Xd5DZDFeTgZw=","DESTINO":"OOcb8QTlctDfYOwjBI02hUJ1o3Bro/ir6IsmZRigja0=","PRECIO":0.001103046357615894,"RESERVA":"2015-04-08","SALIDA":"2015-07-24","LLEGADA":"2015-07-24","DISTANCIA":0.21382548869717155,"EDAD":"13","sexo":"M"}
```

So, I'm using the following code to read each line into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import json
import gzip
import pandas as pd
import random

with gzip.GzipFile('data/000000000000.json.gz', 'r',) as fin:
    data_lan = pd.DataFrame()
    for line in fin:
        data_lan = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))]).append(data_lan)
```

But it's taking years. 
Any suggestion to read the data quicker?

EDIT:
Finally what solved the problem:

```
import json
import gzip
import pandas as pd

with gzip.GzipFile('data/000000000000.json.gz', 'r',) as fin:
    data_lan = []
    for line in fin:
        data_lan.append(json.loads(line.decode('utf-8')))

data = pd.DataFrame(data_lan)
```

Comment: That `append` looks suspicious. Maybe you are encountering accidentally quadratic time complexity?

Comment: I don't really know how `pd.DataFrame`s work, but did you mean something like this: `data_lan.append(pd.DataFrame([json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))]))` (instead of appending `data_lan` *to itself*)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 You are right, the 'data = ' is not necessary.  Anyway, it doesn't seem to improve the time execution.

Comment: Append creates a new dataframe by copying the original frame plus the new row. So, you copy the entire existing frame on each iteration and that is very slow. If the file is not too big for memory, reading it first into an outer list is preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked on a similar problem myself, The `append()` is kinda slow. I generally use a `list` of `dicts` to load the json file and then create a `Dataframe` at once. This ways, you can have the flexibility the lists give you and only when you're sure about the Data in the list you convert it into a `Dataframe`. Below is an implementation of the concept:

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip


def get_contents_from_json(file_path)-> dict:
    """
    Reads the contents of the json file into a dict
    :param file_path:
    :return: A dictionary of all contents in the file.
    """
    try:
        with gzip.open(file_path) as file:
            contents = file.read()
        return json.loads(contents.decode('UTF-8'))
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        print('Error while reading json file')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f'The JSON file was not found at the given path: \n{file_path}')


def main(file_path: str):
    file_contents = get_contents_from_json(file_path)
    if not isinstance(file_contents,list):
        # I've considered you have a JSON Array in your file
        # if not let me know in the comments
        raise TypeError("The file doesn't have a JSON Array!!!")
    all_columns = file_contents[0].keys()
    data_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=all_columns, data=file_contents)
    print(f'Loaded {int(data_frame.size / len(all_columns))} Rows', 'Done!', sep='\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(r'C:\Users\carrot\Desktop\dummyData.json.gz')
```

Comment: Thank you. I finally used your suggestion and I first read the file into a list. Then a passed the list to a pandas DataFrame and everything worked pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

A `pandas` `DataFrame` fits into a contiguous block of memory which means that `pandas` needs to know the size of the data set when the frame is created. Since `append` changes the size, new memory must be allocated and the original plus new data sets are copied in. As your set grows, the copy gets bigger and bigger.

You can use `from_records` to avoid this problem. First, you need to know the row count and that means scanning the file. You could potentially cache that number if you do it often, but its a relatively fast operation. Now you have the size and pandas can allocate the memory efficiently.

```
# count rows
with gzip.GzipFile(file_to_test, 'r',) as fin:
    row_count = sum(1 for _ in fin)

# build dataframe from records
with gzip.GzipFile(file_to_test, 'r',) as fin:
    data_lan = pd.DataFrame.from_records(fin, nrows=row_count)
```